# Separate JSON objects with JSON.NET (vb)

Tags: json, vb.net, parsing, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I am having trouble separating pieces of a JSON object. Inside the json string there are 3 objects. One is called "JSONData", which I need to separate into its own object. I have tried so many things I'm starting to lose track. Two of which that seems to have been most helpful are below. However, they both end up empty. No errors, just empty. Hopefully someone can help!!

```
Dim j As String = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(xml) 'Started out as XML
Dim o As JObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(j) 'Then Json String to JObject
Dim channel As JObject = DirectCast(o("JSONData"), JObject) 'Try #1 to separate
'/// or
Dim jsondata As String = o.Item("JSONData") 'Try #2
'/// i have tried both above with ("IMSXMLLog.JSONData") as well. Same Result.
```

[image: screencast]
https://jsfiddle.net/jharris8567/v23kj42v/ - Full JSON

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JSONData` is inside another object `IMSXMLLog`, so your inclination to use the path `IMSXMLLog.JSONData` is correct.  However, the indexer on `JToken` does not support paths, only single property names.  To use path syntax you need to use the `SelectToken` method:

```
Dim data as JObject = DirectCast(o.SelectToken("IMSXMLLog.JSONData"), JObject)
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Wu70Tu

Comment: AH! SOOO CLOSE!! Thanks so much!